# Insert sql com regra WHERE NOT EXISTS não funciona

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Nesse insert abaixo só funciona até a primeira regra do "Where" depois não funciona mais

Exemplo

```
WHERE descricao ='$ccusto'  // funciona perfeitamente. Mas se uso o where abaixo

WHERE descricao ='$ccusto' AND id_transfer ='$id_transfer' AND id_empresa='$id_empresa')");
                           // já não funciona


echo $id_transfer22 = 555;
echo $id_empresa = 555; 
echo $ccusto = 'obaoba';
echo $id_novo8= 555;
$sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO c_custo(id_transfer,id_empresa,descricao,cod) 
SELECT '$id_transfer22','$id_empresa','$ccusto','$cod' 
FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT descricao,id_empresa,id_transfer FROM c_custo
WHERE descricao ='$ccusto' AND id_transfer ='$id_transfer' AND id_empresa='$id_empresa')");
```

Oque posso estar fazndo de errado?

Comment: Opa, lendo de novo a pergunta entendi o que você quer: Fazer INSERT do que vier no SELECT na tabela c_custo, sendo que usando o where da primeira forma funciona e da segunda forma não e quer corrigir pra conseguir da segunda forma também.

Comment: Põe essa query numa variável, dá um echo na tela e roda direto no banco. Testa antes o SELECT sozinho pra ver se está vindo algo. Meu palpite é que quando você inclui esses detalhes a mais não existe nenhum registro no banco satisfazendo essa consulta.

Comment: Ola Colocando a query no mysql está funcionando perfeitamente retorna 5 itens reptidos, portanto não deveria aceitar o insert pois ja tem registros iguais

Comment: Olha a resposta do Mike nesse tópico do SOen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table